# Why is CORS blocking an sms://-link?

Tags: cors

I'm trying to create a link that opens the messenger-service like this:

```
<a href="sms://+99-999-99-99">send text message</a>
```

But this triggers a CORS-error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at sms://+99-999-99-99. (Reason: CORS-Request wasn't http).

Interestingly, when I try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gSPEe/ - I don't get that error and the browser is asking to open the message-app.

What do I need to do on my server/htaccess/webpage so this works?

Comment: The CORS error doesn't happen in normal circumstances. There is *something else* on your page reading that link and trying to open it in a different way.

Comment: Damn - yep, you were right. I had a js-action on links in that container. Totally forgot about that. THANKS!!!